# Limitar vezes do While - ArrayIterator

Tags: php, while

Estou fazendo duas consultas em tabelas diferentes do BD para gerar uma página com diferentes exibições dependendo do resultado. Para isso, estou montando em cada consulta um While diferente. Na verdade, um está dentro do outro, inseridos em uma lógica condicional.

O código:

```
<?php
$sessao = new Sessao;
$dados = $sessao->listarSessao();
if(empty($dados)):
    echo "Nenhum serviço cadastrado";
else:
    $p = new ArrayIterator($dados);
    while($p->valid()):
        if($p->current()->exibe == 1){
?>
            <div id="sessao-list">
                <div class="tSession">Sessão <?php echo $p->current()->numero_sessao; ?></div>
                <div class="textS"><?php echo $p->current()->nome_sessao; ?></div>
                <div class="Access"><a href="sessao.php?link=<?php echo $_GET['link']; ?>&servico=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&id=<?php echo $p->current()->id; ?>" title="<?php echo $p->current()->nome_sessao; ?>" class="info-tooltip" target="_self"><img src="images/shared/access.png"/></a></div>
            </div>
<?php 
        } else {
            $session = new Sessao;
            $infos = $session->liberarSessao();
            $i = new ArrayIterator($infos);
            while($i->valid()):
                if($p->current()->id == $i->current()->id_sessao){
?>
                    <div id="sessao-list">
                        <div class="tSession">Sessão <?php echo $p->current()->numero_sessao; ?></div>
                        <div class="textS"><?php echo $p->current()->nome_sessao; ?></div>
                        <div class="Access"><a href="sessao.php?link=<?php echo $_GET['link']; ?>&servico=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&id=<?php echo $p->current()->id; ?>" title="<?php echo $p->current()->nome_sessao; ?>" class="info-tooltip" target="_self"><img src="images/shared/access.png"/></a></div>
                    </div>

<?php 
                } else {
?>
                    <div id="sessao-list">
                        <div class="tSessionD">Sessão <?php echo $p->current()->numero_sessao; ?></div>
                        <div class="textSD"><?php echo $p->current()->nome_sessao; ?></div>
                    </div>

<?php
                };
                $i->next();
            endwhile;
        };
        $p->next();

    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Estou usado ArrayIterator e ambas as consultas estão numa classe Sessao.php.
A lógica deveria ser:

1) Se o campo "exibe" da tabela "sessoes" for igual a 1, exibe html "completo"; caso contrário, cai na segunda verificação...

2) Se existe registro daquela sessão para aquele usuário na tabela "sess_users", exibe HTML "completo"; caso contrário, exibe HTML "simplificado".

As consultas na classe Sessao.php estão assim:

```
public function listarSessao(){
    $pdo = parent::getDB();
    $listarSessao = $pdo->prepare("select * from sessoes WHERE id_servico =" .$_GET['id']. " ORDER BY id ASC");
    $listarSessao->execute();
    return $listarSessao->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

public function liberarSessao(){
    $pdo = parent::getDB();
    $liberarSessao = $pdo->prepare("select * from sess_users WHERE id_servico =" .$_GET['id']. " AND id_user=" .$_SESSION['usrid']. " ORDER BY id ASC");
    $liberarSessao->execute();
    return $liberarSessao->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

O problema é que o segundo While está duplicando cada registro, tantas vezes quantos registros existem na tabela "sess_users". Acredito que, se houver alguma maneira de limitar o laço em 1 vez, o problema seria resolvido. Ou existe alguma outra forma de fazer?

Comment: Acredito que seu problema primordial está localizado nas consultas realizadas por `Sessao.php`. Provavelmente está faltando um filtro na segunda consulta (while interno) que faça referência à primeira consulta (while externo).

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e inserir o código das duas consultas, obrigado.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu tentei reescrever a consulta da função **listarSessao** usando INNER JOIN, dessa forma: `SELECT DISTINCT sessoes.* FROM sessoes INNER JOIN sess_users ON sess_users.id_servico = sessoes.id_servico WHERE sessoes.id_servico = ".$_GET['id']." AND sess_users.id_user = ".$_SESSION['usrid']." ORDER BY sessoes.id ASC` . E tentei usar apenas esta função nas duas consultas (para cada While). Só que isso não resolveu, pois o IF do segundo While (interno) perde o valor de id_sessao...